# Learn python the hard way exercise 15

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner rigidly following Zed's "Learn python the hard way". 
I got stuck with exercise 15. The example he gave wouldn't run. It keeps returning error: `No such file or directory.`

The script is:

```
 from sys import argv
 script, filename = argv

 txt = open(filename)
 print "\n Here is your file %r: " % script
 print txt.read()


print "I'll also ask you to type it again."
new_file = raw_input(">>>")
new_txt = open(new_file)
print new_txt.read()
```

The problem starts with the "new_txt = open(new_file)" line. The file is no where in my directory, hence couldn't run. 
pls someone should help point me to the right path. Thanks.

Comment: What is exercise 15? please try to make a [mcve]

Comment: What command line did you use to run your script ? It takes a parameter for the file to read. In addition, what did you type in console when the script displayed '>>>' ?

Comment: *“The file is no where in my directory”* – You seem to already know why it doesn’t work, so what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: In any case, you should consider switching to a different Python tutorial. LPTHW has [quite a few issues](https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

Comment: I used wndows powershell. I typed in strings of words.

Comment: @poke, new_file in the script is just a variable. When i try the open() on it, it returns error (No such file/directory). What I don't get though, is why the script runs fine in the example the instructor provided.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the *exact* command you entered in powershell (and "I typed in string of words" is completely useless in this regard.) Without complete information about what you did, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, Michail N suggested I typed in an existing file when prompted. I tried that and it worked. Thank you very much and don't get pissed just yet with my silly questions, I'm sure I'll be coming back with some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is:

```
script, filename = argv
```

This means that the program is run with arguments. The first argument is always the program name so the second argument should be the filename you want to read (assuming it exists in the right path). 
So you should run the program with from command line with:

```
python programName.py yourFileName
```

Then in

```
new_file = raw_input(">>>")
```

it reads another filename from your keyboard input. You could enter another valid file or the same to read it again. Hope this helps.

**Note:** You got the down votes because you mentioned unrelated information to your question (the source and that is question 15) which are no useful at all. You should simply asked what this code do if you don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks a million. This just solved it. I ought to have included a file name instead. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help but you should close the question next. Type the green tick near my answer.